# error while installing cassandra in windows

Tags: cassandra

```
 INFO 19:07:42,273 GC for ParNew: 2182 ms, 27013384 reclaimed leaving 215461536
used; max is 1171062784
 INFO 19:07:44,382 Pool Name                    Active   Pending
 INFO 19:07:44,960 ReadStage                         0         0
 INFO 19:07:44,976 RequestResponseStage              0         0
 INFO 19:07:44,976 ReadRepairStage                   0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,007 MutationStage                     0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,007 GossipStage                       0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,007 AntiEntropyStage                  0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,007 MigrationStage                    0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,007 StreamStage                       0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,022 MemtablePostFlusher               0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,022 FlushWriter                       0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,022 MiscStage                         0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,022 FlushSorter                       0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,038 InternalResponseStage             0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,038 HintedHandoff                     0         0
 INFO 19:07:45,085 CompactionManager               n/a         0
 INFO 19:07:45,101 MessagingService                n/a       0,0
 INFO 19:07:45,116 ColumnFamily                Memtable ops,data  Row cache siz
/cap  Key cache size/cap
 INFO 19:07:45,288 system.LocationInfo                       0,0
 0/0                 1/1
 INFO 19:07:45,304 system.HintsColumnFamily                  0,0
 0/0                 0/1
 INFO 19:07:45,319 system.Migrations                         0,0
 0/0                 0/1
 INFO 19:07:45,319 system.Schema                             0,0
 0/0                 0/1
 INFO 19:07:45,319 system.IndexInfo                          0,0
 0/0                 0/1
```

After this my installation process does not proceed. It generally hangs showing:

```
Listening for thrift clients....
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats exactly what you want to see if your cassandra node/cluster is up and running.

Comment: but it is repeating the same message.... i wait for 2hrs to get installtion complete

Answer (score 1):

Schildmeijer is correct - this is a normal log output from *running* Cassandra after a successful installation.

If you are unsure, then try running the Cassandra CLI (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli) and execute some commands to check that the server node responds.

Cassandra runs as a server process - you don't interact directly with it, only via the CLI or another client tool.